# read value from textnode selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, browser-automation

I have a web app .I am testing it using selenium. I have a node

```
<span>Profile Run <span class="current">23</span> of 29</span>
```

I want to read "of 29"

I used the XPath

```
//span[contains(text(),'Profile Run')]/text()[last()]
```

But `getAttribute("innerText")`, `getAttribute("innerHTML")` even `getText()` is not working.

Error:

> the result of xpath expression 
>   *//span[contains(text(),'Profile Run')]/text()[last()] is: [object Text]. It should be an element.*

Comment: Did you try to get element first `//span[contains(text(),'Profile Run')]` and from there it's easy to get text content?

Comment: @dsfq It returns entire span as an web element. I want only " of 29"

Comment: I know, that's what I'm saying: get entire span, then get last children. Easy.

Comment: @dsfq u mean something like this driver.findElement(By.xpath(hmap("//span[contains(text(),'Profile Run')]")).getAttribute("innerHTML"

Comment: Something like this: `driver.findElement(By.xpath(hmap("//span[contains(text(),'Profile Run')]")).lastChild`

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement splitEnd =  driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//span[contains(text(),'Profile Run')]")));
       splitEnd.toString().split("ADD VALUE THAT YOU WANT TO RETURN");
```

What going to happen here is It will return all value of your span. It will entire span and converting span in string and using string function "split" You can take value what you exactly want to extract from your code

Here is split function document : 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.